# How to customize the Daily Saving Time in windows to override the DateTime in .Net

Tags: .net, datetime, timezone

Today the DST applied on the windows which is a week early in Iran. It troubles my .Net applications which are sensitive to correct date time.

Is there any way to change this for the server?

I want to set something in Server or .Net to set the correct DST of Tehran.

Comment: Not that I am aware of. The "correct" way to fix this, in my opinion, is to use `DateTimeOffset` and ensure all times in your application are stored in UTC time.

Comment: @vcsjones All times are stored in UTC, but it should be converted with +4:30 offset instead of +3:30.

Comment: @mehrandvd: If my understanding of your question is correct, you can use [this solution](http://www.dotnettips.info/post/1033/)

Comment: Please ask this question on [SuperUser.com](http://superuser.com), as it is a good question, but is off-topic for StackOverflow since it is related to the Windows OS and not to programming.  When you do, please provide more specific details, such as the expected and actual dates of the Daylight Saving Time transition.

Comment: @MattJohnson I thought there might be a solution with .Net to override the DST too.